# PHP Errorcode: expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

i try build an app where u register you in a mysqli db from your own android device.
I get many warnings at my php script.

`Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/a3074158/public_html/Register.php on line 12
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a3074158/public_html/Register.php on line 13
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a3074158/public_html/Register.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a3074158/public_html/Register.php on line 16
Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a3074158/public_html/Register.php on line 19`

there ist my code

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: " . $connect->connect_error);
}
$name= $_Post["name"];
$alter= $_Post["alter"];
$passwort= $_Post["passwort"];
$username= $_Post["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "Insert into User (name, alter, username, passwort) VALUe(?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"siss", $user, $alter, $username, $passwort);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);  


mysqli_close($connect);
```

?>

Its my first try, any ideas/tips/tutorials?

Comment: Your error reporting is active and set to `E_ALL`? => `$connect = mysqli_connect` => `if ($conn->connect_error)`

Comment: Thanks. Adapted, is that what you mean?

Comment: You missed the conditional edit, `!$connect>connect_error`.

Comment: See @Ohgodwhy answer.

Comment: In addition to that answer `alter` is a reserved keyword and needs to be in backticks or renamed. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @chris85 in front of "alter" evertime stands "$". So its a variable. Or ignore php the sign? Thanks for the note.

Comment: `Insert into User (name, alter, username`  that is SQL. Alter is a reserved term in SQL. So once you get this making it to the DB it will still be failing because of that. The `alter` needs to be `\`alter\``.

Comment: Okay, and now you are just missing the conditional line still `if(!$connect){` not `if (!$connect>connect_error) {`.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, i get a syntax error.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was going to roll it back to the start, but I decided that the answer below does not address the actual issue and is nothing more than a comment. The problem is likely with a code we can't see or the database, so this makes this question off-topic. If `$connect` is false then there should be a warning generated by `mysqli_connect`, which is not there. `$conn` should also throw a notice. It doesn't look like this question is answerable.

Comment: @Dharman thank you. I added my vote

Answer (score -1):

it should be

```
if(!$connect){
    die('Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

So you're not hitting that conditional and the `prepare` is failing.

This is because you're using `procedural` methods and not `object oriented` methods.

**Edit**

As user @chris85 pointed out below, you are also using a `MySQL Reserved Word` in your table structure by using **alter**.

If you don't want to change the columnname, then the column name needs to be escaped with backticks: `` `alter` ``. You must use this everytime you query on the column.